# Share via URL scheme to Signal

Tags: html, web, url-scheme

I'm looking for a way to create Signal share button

```
<a href="https://wa.me/send?text=message"></a>
```

This is whatsapp sample I'm looking for similar solution for signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,
**signal.me/#p/+phonenumber**
For additional info, go [here](https://community.signalusers.org/t/add-custom-url-scheme-signal-or-sgnl-for-share-or-call-buttons-on-websites/2362).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As today, sadly, there is no official way of implementing this.